# How do I find what collections a collection is part of?

Tags: python, collections

I am trying to build a collection hierarchy in bpy - to mirror a product's hierarchical bill of materials.

With a mesh I can do this:

```
obj.users_collection
```

to find out what collections object `obj` is part of.

How do I do that with a collection? if I do

```
coll.users_collection
```

I get an error:

```
'Collection' object has no attribute 'users_collection'
```

and

```
coll.users_dupli_group
```

(which was my best guess) returns an empty list, and not at least the root collection as I expected: a behavior that is different from plain Objects.

So what should I use instead?

For context - I am trying to do the following:

- create a new collection "A"
- add an existing collection "B" to the new collection "A"
- if the existing collection was in some other collection (including the top one), unlink it so "B" is in one collection only - that is, in "A"

This last step fail - as I can't seem tell what collections a collection is in.

Comment: @brockmann - yeah, it looks like it could work, I'm going to test that out later. So do I get it right that you can get the parent of an Object (with users_collection), but not of a Collection?

Comment: As I wrote: "As long as there is no parent property..."